# Use Control-C instead of escape key

Tags: neovim

I have recently found out that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> can be used instead of <kbd>Esc</kbd> in certain instances. Getting out of insert mode for instance. Other things can only exclusively exited using escape.
So my question is, is it possible to completely replace the escape key with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>? So that it works exactly the same?

Comment: nice answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030164/whats-the-difference-between-ctrlc-and-ctrl

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are some (often subtle) differences between <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to leave Insert mode.

For instance, [`:help i_CTRL-C`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-C) mentions some of them:

> `CTRL-C`: Quit insert mode, go back to Normal mode.  Do not check for abbreviations.  Does not trigger the `InsertLeave` autocommand event.

Another difference happens when you enter Insert mode with a count, in which case <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will cancel the repetition from the count. To illustrate, `3iabc<Esc>` will insert `abcabcabc`, while `3iabc<C-c>` will insert simply `abc`.

If you want to make <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> exactly equivalent to <kbd>Esc</kbd>, you can use a mapping to do so:

```
imap <C-c> <Esc>
```

Another option (if you're looking for a replacement for the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, either because your keyboard doesn't have one or because you find its location inconvenient) is to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>, which is exactly equivalent to <kbd>Esc</kbd>, it produces the exact same keystroke so both key combinations are effectively indistinguishable to Vim.

Comment: Yeah problem is, my keyboard layout makes control-] unreachable. Is there really no way to just remap it to c-c

Comment: @user2741831 Yes there is, see the answer, `imap <C-c> <Esc>` might be exactly what you want to make `<C-c>` behave exactly like `<Esc>`. You might want to also map that in other modes (Visual, Select, etc.) Perhaps in all modes: `map <C-c> <Esc>` and `map! <C-c> <Esc>` will do that.

Comment: Any reason not to noremap instead of map?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I thought this was one case where using a recursive map was appropriate, since it's likely you want to replace the key in *all* contexts and that potentially includes other mappings. Does that make sense?

Comment: @filbranden kind of? The mapping being recursive only means remapping escape also affects ctrl-c..

Comment: Interestingly, `C-[` also works in gVim, where, technically, it should be distinguishable from `Esc` (via GDK events). Moreover, even QtCreator's FakeVim implements this shortcut.

Comment: @Ruslan Yeah, some of Vim's limitations are somewhat artificial, they're baked in due to the terminal origin of vi/vim and I guess for simplicity and consistency between different target platforms...

Comment: @filbranden Note that it's quite easy in all OSes to swap CapsLock and Escape. It's a solution adopted by a lot of vimmers and makes life much easier.

Answer (score 4):

I do not think it is good idea to use CTRL-C instead of ESC since it does not do some useful things like following (from `:h i_CTRL-C`) and can break some plugins.

```
    *i_CTRL-C*
CTRL-C      Quit insert mode, go back to Normal mode.  Do not check for
        abbreviations.  Does not trigger the |InsertLeave| autocommand
        event.
```

But if really want it you can remap:

```
inoremap <ESC> <C-C>
```

Also you maybe want to know that `<C-[>` is equal to `<ESC>`. And if you worry about speed of typing think about this mapping:

```
inoremap jj <Esc>
```

Comment: Note that your first `inoremap` is backwards, you're mapping Esc to Ctrl-C and not Ctrl-C to Esc. With the second mapping, you might want to explain what that does and why you'd use that, it might not be obvious to a beginner...